# Proof for the relationship among three events without knowing whether they are independent

Tags: probability, independence

For three events $A, B$, and $C$, if we have $P(A|C) \ge P(B|C)$ and $P(A | C^c) \ge P(B|C^c)$, then can we prove $P(A) \ge P(B)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$P(A)=P(A|C)P(C)+P(A|C^c)P(C^c)$$

write a similar expression for $P(B)$ too.